# vorpal .validate throwing error

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, argv, vorpal.js

I have a vorpal command that looks like this:
I am running version 1.9.5.

```
const vorpal = require('vorpal')()

vorpal
   .command('temp [dev]')
   .validate(function() {
     return false
   })
   .action(function() {
     ...
   })

vorpal.parse(process.argv)
```

And when i run `pnt temp` in my terminal I get this error thrown:

```
/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/vorpal.js:169
          throw new Error(err);
          ^

Error: null
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/vorpal.js:169:17)
    at callback (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/vorpal.js:830:22)
    at /Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/vorpal.js:961:7
    at EventEmitter._commandSetCallback (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/session.js:446:5)
    at EventEmitter.session.completeCommand (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/session.js:526:12)
    at onCompletion (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/session.js:456:10)
    at EventEmitter.session.execCommandSet (/Users/samm/Sites/p nt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/session.js:471:5)
    at EventEmitter.vorpal._exec (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/vorpal.js:960:18)
    at EventEmitter.vorpal._execQueueItem (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/vorpal.js:751:17)
    at EventEmitter.vorpal._queueHandler (/Users/samm/Sites/pnt/node_modules/vorpal/dist/vorpal.js:735:10)
```

Comment: How are you initializing `vorpal`? Please update your question with that code.

Comment: I have updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

I admit that this is looking ugly, and they will probably fix this in future versions, but this looks like the correct behaviour.

Returning `false` or a string from `.validate` should throw an error, as this means that you don't accept the arguments. If you return a string that string will be shown to the user (`return "I don't want no scrubs."`).

So from the code that you posted this is the correct behaviour.

If you like the errormessage from `.validate` to be different, I recommend you post an issue on vorpal's issue tracker. (Even though I can see you have already done that).

Comment: If i do it with a string instead of just return false I get the text logged and then the same error again, this doesnt seem like standard behaviour

Comment: You didn't specify in your question what behaviour you want when you don't allow the parameters. Anyway this is how the framework functions, and it looks like it is the expected and wanted behaviour.

Comment: I just thought it was a bug as I could of sworn in earlier version if the validation didnt pass it would just exit the commmand with whatever string you put in the return

Comment: From other comments it looks like `.validate` was implemented in november/december 2015, and the recommended way of doing it was to check for the parameters after `.parse` was run. Therefore no error was thrown, but you were free to do as you wanted.

Comment: Ah right, maybe Im missuing validate then, I dont pass any args to the validate function Im actually running another function that authorises against a api